# Apache configuration for a simple test page

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to get a handle on Apache configuration files. One of the things I want to do is move some webpages away from the /var/www directory. I have a working configuration in my own pc (name is pc01). There is a webpage I use for tests in /var/www/compile/ and inside there is a single page file: compile.php.

I moved the compile folder to /home/web/compile. And I created this configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ctest

        DocumentRoot /home/web/compile/
        <Directory />
                Order Allow,Deny
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/compile.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

As I understand the tutorials I have used if I point my browser to pc01/ctest/compile.php I should see the webpage. However All I get is:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /ctest/compile.php on this server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the access rights for `/home/web/compile/`? eg. `<Directory /home/web/compile/> Order Allow, Deny
 Allow From All</Directory>`

Comment: what is file permission of compile.php
try giving it 777  for testing however a php file on server must have file permission of 644 and a directory should have 755

Comment: I did not add the <Directory> part because I thought it was not necessary. See update form y code

Answer (score 0):

You need to set file owner to apache user (user running web server).
Default user for web server is www-data. Try this command in terminal:

> chown www-data:www-data /home/web/compile -R

Comment: The folder belongs to a group named webdev to which www-data and myself belong. I has all rights. When I used the previous configuration (file 000-default.conf that was installed with the server) this worked perfectly. I tried chown anyways but it did not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Found it!! The key was to modify the apache2.conf file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf in Debian) to add another document root other than /var/www. Then it started working. Thanks for the help!